# Run a javascript function on click of popup icon of chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

As chrome.browserAction.onClicked works only if there is no popup, is there any alternative method to fire a query when browser action icon is clicked?

Let me make myself clear..
I have more than one view i.e, html files in my extension. My default popup in index.html
Whenever I click on the icon I want to fetch some data from server. If I include this function in index.html or index.js, this function gets called every time I go to that page. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand: you say "*If I include this function in index.html or index.js, this function gets called every time I go to that page*," but isn't that the correct behavior?  Do you mean the user can visit `index.html` some way other than as a popup?

Comment: Actually index.html can be reached from other view pages in popup.

Comment: I think we can use sessionStorage for this purpose. It actually worked for me. sessionStorage data gets cleared once popup is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is:

1. Have the behavior take place in the `onload` handler of the page.  Since it sounds like the default popup page, `index.html`, can be loaded as time when the user is not creating the initial popup, I would create a page that is a *dedicated initial popup load page* that is not used anywhere else.  This page could redirect to `index.html` or include it as an iframe.
2. Another option is to have `index.html` take a query string indicating how it is being used.  Your initial popup could be `index.html?init=1` and all other inclusions of the page simply use `index.html`.  Then use `window.location.search.substring(1)` to test if a query string is present and take the appropriate action.

Comment: Thank you very much. This way sounds fine but as of now I got it working using sessioStorage. Is it advised? I am asking this because I just want to learn as I am new to chrome extensions.

Comment: Apparently the Chromium devs think that using a new `sessionStorage` for each new popup [is actually a *bug*](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42599).  What I gather from this bug report is that the "ideal" behavior would be to preserve `sessionStorage` between popups.  See the MDN page on [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage): "*A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores*."  This means that the popup should *not* get a new `sessionStorage` object each time the popup opens.

Comment: So, in sum, if you rely on having a new `sessionStorage` each time you open the popup, you'll be relying on a bug, which will probably get fixed eventually.  I highly recommend my query-string solution (#2), since that is logically very similar to your `sessionStorage` solution.  Instead of checking if a flag is not yet set in `sessionStorage`, check if `window.location.search` is non-empty.

Comment: Thank You very much. I will change over to your approach :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for an solution to this and I'm wondering if it is possible to start the browser action with no popup, [detect the click](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked), then set a popup with "[setPopup()](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setPopup)". If it works it doesn't seem like the nicest approach, I hope someone knows of a better solution.

Comment: This requires the user the click the button twice -- once to trigger the onclick event and once to show the popup.

Comment: I think we can use sessionStorage for this purpose. It actually worked for me. sessionStorage data gets cleared once popup is closed.